# Netbeans - Project debug is failing(Web Application)

Tags: java-8, tomcat8, netbeans-8

I have a war file , when i run the project it gets deployed in the Tomcat-8.0.
But when i want to debug and run debug from project window ,tomcat fails to deploy the war in the tomcat.
 with the below error

```
ERROR: transport error 202: failed to accept shared memory connection: stream closed
JDWP exit error JVMTI_ERROR_NONE(0): could not connect, timeout or fatal error [transport.c:326]
```

Comment: Does this blog post help?.... http://petersnotes.blogspot.com/2010/01/netbeans-and-tomcat-shared-memory-realm.html

Answer (score 3):

Switch from using shared memory to socket port. To do this from within NetBeans select Tools > Servers. In the window that opens select the Tomcat server that you wish to modify. Select the Startup tab and then change the Debugger Transport from Shared Memory Name to Socket Port. You can set a specific port if you wan’t but it’s unlikely that the currently selected port is in use. When you are finished close the server settings window, kill the Tomcat process and then start it up again. You should now find that the debugger will run perfectly

Reference :

[NetBeans and Tomcat – Transport Error 202](http://www.naturalborncoder.com/java/java-ee/2015/11/25/netbeans-and-tomcat-transport-error-202/)